# REGEX: \Z in character class

Tags: python, regex, character-class

REGEX:

```
((?<=blah)[^@\Z]+)
```

It supposed to capture symbols symbols that preceded by `blah` and ending with `@` or end of string.
Is correct technique to enclose `\Z` in character class ?

Comment: You are matching things that are *not* `@` (the `^` negates the character group), but your narrative suggests that that is an error. Could you clarify?

Comment: By 'ending' I meant that sequence must be limited at the end with that character (or with end of string)

Comment: Then you should *not* use the `^` caret to negate the character class.

Comment: Why?? Matcher firstly match 'blah' and then capture one or more characters before he find symbols from [^] - that was my logic

Comment: So you want to match `blahsomethingnottheend@` as well as `blahsomethingnottheend`?

Comment: From string 'tralalablahsomethingtotheend@' - 'somethingtotheend'

Comment: 'Then you still need to mention @ or \Z explicitly' Why - I always have that group (most outer one), and why need use non-capturing group in your regex? Isnt it will stop 'eating' string when hits @ when @ negated in class?

Comment: Yes, it'll stop eating when it hits '@' or the end of the string. Good point. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, character classes can only contain literal characters or other character classes; your example matches anything that is *not* a `@`, the `\Z` anchor, is ignored as it is not a character class itself. Note that the `^` caret negates the character group. Use a group instead with a `|` 'or' symbol instead:

```
((?<=blah)(?:[^@]+|\Z))
```

I used a non-capturing group there (`(?:...)`) to group the two options. The group matches any characters that are *not* `@`, *or* it matches the `\Z` end-of-string anchor.

Comment: Thank you! This regex is greedy or non-greedy?

Comment: @GillBates: The `+` is greedy, add a `?` behind it to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Maybe it is better to user negative lookahead instead of non-capturing group?

Comment: @GillBates: that depends entirely on what you are trying to match. Look-ahead and look-behind are used to anchor a match, they are not part of the matched characters themselves. Use them as advanced versions of `\Z`, `^` and `$`.

Comment: Technically, a character class can contain things that are not literal characters.  The point is that anything they contain must resolve to a one-character element, and `\Z` means `(?:\n?\z)`, so won’t work.  Another way to say what needs saying is that cannot put boundaries in a character class, since a boundary is not a character.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The `[^@\Z]` does negate `@`, but it does not negate either ``\`` or `Z` in Python 3.2.3 (which I tested on).

Comment: @nhahtdh: Indeed, I stand corrected. The `\Z` escape is treated as a character class itself and thus can be inserted into a `[]` larger class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Not sure if it is treated as character class or not. But it doesn't seem that it will have any effect.

Comment: @tchrist: It is not an error to put `\Z` in the character class, but it then won't match anything either. In my tests a `[\Z]` character class grouping does not match anything.

Comment: I would expect `[\Z]` to match `Z` itself, or probably a backslash too.

Comment: @tchrist: It doesn't. You can put `\d` in a character class (`[a-f\d]` is a valid class for hex characters), hence my assumption `\Z` is being treated as a class too.

Comment: Seems like a good place for `Unrecognized escape \Z in character class passed through in regex` to pop up.

Comment: @tchrist: Interestingly enough, combining `\Z` with other character groups throws an `sre_constants.error: internal: unsupported set operator` exception.